# Изменение изображения ссылки при нажатии

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть ссылка которая разворачивает список, у нее стоит background стрелка направленная вниз, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку (когда список развернулся) background поменялся на стрелку вверх (картинка есть)? помогите прописать код

Comment: А, в чём конкретно проблема? Поясните, что конкретно не получается. Выложите пример, пусть не работающего, но **Вашего кода**. Иначе голосую за закрытие.

Comment: а в чем же проблема? http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/4vogbfby/

Comment: просто при клике меняете background на нужную картинку

Comment: Могли бы вы прописать как поменять background?
Например: 
a {
background: url(1.png);
}
a:active {
background: url(2.png);
} 
Так ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На основе [другого моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468033/178988):

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 20em;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px; /* (20-16)/2 */
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAApklEQVQ4T2NkQAJ7Tl4LYGT4v56B8f8EZzOdQmQ5XGxGZIm9J64VMDD+7weL/WdY4GyhnUjIEBQDQIr3nLyygJGBMZ5YQzAMINUQrAaQYghOA4g1BK8BxBhC0AAMQxgZEp3NtBfAYof2BiBH63+G/wtdzHUSkNMG0YGITTPIIKKiEZdmnAYQcjZeL5CiGcMFyJkJn7NxugCenf//n+hsoVNAKCeC5AFAFmkRt17xCgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover {
  background: #FC8;
}

label + ul > li {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label + ul > li {
  display: list-item;
}

input:checked + label + ul:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg); /* or set some other picture here */
}
```

```html
<nav><ul>
  <li><input type=checkbox id=nav-1><label for=nav-1>1</label><ul>
    <li>1.1</li>
    <li>1.2</li>
    <li>1.3</li>
    <li>1.4</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li><input type=checkbox id=nav-2><label for=nav-2>2</label><ul>
    <li>2.1</li>
    <li>2.2</li>
    <li>2.3</li>
    <li>2.4</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li><input type=checkbox id=nav-3><label for=nav-3>3</label><ul>
    <li>5.1</li>
    <li>5.2</li>
    <li>5.3</li>
    <li>5.4</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо ) 
А есть какой-то быстрый способ сделать это в Bootstrap 3   ?