# Выбрать элемент, который содержит другой элемент css

Tags: css

Можно ли на чистом css получить элемент, который содержит другой элемент?
На примере у нас многоуровневое меню.

Задача: добавить стрелочку к пункту, который содержит вложенное меню.

```
.menu_header ul li ul li > ul li < ul li{
   background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAApklEQVQ4T2NkQAJ7Tl4LYGT4v56B8f8EZzOdQmQ5XGxGZIm9J64VMDD+7weL/WdY4GyhnUjIEBQDQIr3nLyygJGBMZ5YQzAMINUQrAaQYghOA4g1BK8BxBhC0AAMQxgZEp3NtBfAYof2BiBH63+G/wtdzHUSkNMG0YGITTPIIKKiEZdmnAYQcjZeL5CiGcMFyJkJn7NxugCenf//n+hsoVNAKCeC5AFAFmkRt17xCgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: right center;
}
```

Comment: Силекторы `css` движутся только в одну строну, от `родителя` к `ребенку`, обратное движение не возможно, поэтому взять элемент, у которого есть определенный ребенок на чистом `css` нельзя

Comment: И [подобный вопрос на англоязычном SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Comment: Эх! Спасибо ThisMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, на `css` обращение к родителю от дочернего не возможно. Но вы можете воспользоваться например псевдоклассами и добавить стрелку с абсолютным позиционированием относительно родителя.

Comment: Типа after или before?
Я пытался, но так и не получилось. Почему то иконку base64 вообще не видит. И не понятно, как от ребёнка подключить к родителю) Я так понял проще будет сделать скриптом, как бы я не хотел.

Comment: @Владимир да, after и/или before

Answer (score 0):

Дополненная версия: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468043/178988

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px; /* (20-16)/2 */
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAApklEQVQ4T2NkQAJ7Tl4LYGT4v56B8f8EZzOdQmQ5XGxGZIm9J64VMDD+7weL/WdY4GyhnUjIEBQDQIr3nLyygJGBMZ5YQzAMINUQrAaQYghOA4g1BK8BxBhC0AAMQxgZEp3NtBfAYof2BiBH63+G/wtdzHUSkNMG0YGITTPIIKKiEZdmnAYQcjZeL5CiGcMFyJkJn7NxugCenf//n+hsoVNAKCeC5AFAFmkRt17xCgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<nav><ul>
  <li>1<ul>
    <li>1.1</li>
    <li>1.2</li>
    <li>1.3</li>
    <li>1.4</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li>2<ul>
    <li>2.1</li>
    <li>2.2</li>
    <li>2.3</li>
    <li>2.4</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5<ul>
    <li>5.1</li>
    <li>5.2</li>
    <li>5.3</li>
    <li>5.4</li>
  </ul></li>
</ul></nav>
```