# Как сделать аккордеон?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я сделал разворачивание, а сворачивание что-то не получается - как сделать?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".catalogEntryItem").each(function() {
        $(this).on("click",".catalogEntryItemTitle", function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).find("i").toggleClass("arrowDown");
            $(this).parent().find(".catalogEntryItemList").slideToggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYVRBy Собственно сабж. Всем спасибо.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".catalogEntryItem").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click",".catalogEntryItemTitle", function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass("arrowDown");
      $(this).parent().find(".catalogEntryItemList").slideToggle();
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="catalogEntryItem"><a href="" class="catalogEntryItemTitle"><i class="arrow"></i><span>asd</span></a>
  <div class="catalogEntryItemList" style="display: none;"><a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a></div>
</div>
<div class="catalogEntryItem"><a href="" class="catalogEntryItemTitle"><i class="arrow"></i><span>asd</span></a>
  <div class="catalogEntryItemList" style="display: none;"><a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a></div>
</div>
<div class="catalogEntryItem"><a href="" class="catalogEntryItemTitle"><i class="arrow"></i><span>asd</span></a>
  <div class="catalogEntryItemList" style="display: none;"><a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a></div>
</div>
<div class="catalogEntryItem"><a href="" class="catalogEntryItemTitle"><i class="arrow"></i><span>asd</span></a>
  <div class="catalogEntryItemList" style="display: none;"><a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a></div>
</div>
<div class="catalogEntryItem"><a href="" class="catalogEntryItemTitle"><i class="arrow"></i><span>asd</span></a>
  <div class="catalogEntryItemList" style="display: none;"><a href="">dsa</a><a href="">gedgs</a><a href="">sdgbdsgb</a><a href="">sdvgdsv</a></div>
</div>
```

---

*Дополнение:*

Для тех, кто не знает, аккордеон - это набор сворачиваемых блоков, среди которых одновременно только один (или не более одного) может быть в развёрнутом состоянии.

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Как заккордеонить данный код?

Comment: Что сделать с кодом? Вы можете по-русски изъясняться?

Comment: Ну тобишь если одно меню активно, то другие неактивны. Что-то типа bootstrap carousel

Comment: Что означает "заккордеонить"? Это на каком языке? Это на языке быдлокодера :)

Comment: просто сбросить класс актив у всех, и поставить по тому по кому кликнули

Comment: Ну хотя бы "заАккордеонить" написал. В общем, вопрос как сделать аккордеон.

Comment: Просто сбросить класс не получится, тут же ссылка не на родители, а внутри родителя)) помогите))

Comment: @Qwertiy, как бы то ни было, вопрос "_как сделать аккордеон_" + портянка кода  -- это плохой вопрос

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну кода немного. Правда, он несколько сомнительный.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Даже очень плохой вопрос часто можно спасти приличным ответом. Бедж «reversal» придуман не зря.

Comment: @VladD, вы действительно считаете, что вопрос будет полезен еще кому-то кроме ТС?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Не могу судить, js очень уж не моя стихия. (Поэтому не голосую за переоткрытие.)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Но два ответа с суммарным +4 за полчаса дают надежду, что вопрос не так уж плох и скорее всего спасабелен.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос вполне обычный. Его заминусовали за заголовок, который я понял с третьего прочтения, кстати.

Comment: Если кто-нибудь понимает, как вопрос (точнее его заголовок) можно переформулировать - спасайте вопрос)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, "Как сделать аккордеон?"

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот ваш бы вариант через тире ещё бы дополнить расшифровкой по русски.. =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вроде все веб-разработчики в курсе, что такое аккордеон?

Comment: @Qwertiy, только те кто его уже использовали или делали :-D

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если не всем понятен термин *Аккордеон* может стоит расписать например как то так: *Как сделать элемент состоящий из нескольких пунктов в котором один пункт развернут остальные свернуты(Аккордеон)*

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, Перенесите свои объяснения и дополнения из комментариев в поле вопроса, и  тогда можно переоткрывать вопрос.

Comment: @Alexey256, а Войну и мир в заголовок вопроса не запихать? Тебе ж никто не мешает самому внести нужную правку.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Я вообще-то не про заголовок говорил. У всех свое понимания вопроса. На мой взгляд дать код и ссылку на codepen не достаточно.

Comment: @Alexey256, теперь все довольны?

Comment: @Qwertiy если Вы считаете что все **ок**, инициируйте *переоткрытие* я поддержу

Comment: @Bald56rus, я уже голосовал за его переоткрытие - его переоткрыли и сразу закрыли снова. Второй раз проголосовать не могу.

Comment: [Пора на мету](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/Нужно-ли-пояснять-значения-терминов-в-вопросах)

Answer (score 5):

1. Чем не угодил аккордеон из jQueryUI?
   https://jqueryui.com/accordion/
2. Можно вообще только на css такое сделать:
   [Изменение изображения ссылки при нажатии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467965/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/468043#468043) - надо только добавить input'ам одинаковый name и сменить type на radio.
3. Странный код, лучше переделай.
4. Возможно, так:

   ```
   $(".catalogEntryItem.active").not(this)
     .toggleClass("active")
     .find("i").toggleClass("arrowDown");
   ```

Comment: 2 ответа ссылки + комментарий

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, теперь с кодом. Доволен?

Comment: Буду доволен когда перестанете тыкать ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я всегда на программистских сайтах общаюсь на ты. Не стоит воспринимать это негативно, просто привычка :) Кстати, в большинстве мест так и принято.

Comment: Ну все же подскажите как реализовать на jq

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, а у меня на чём? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, `each` в данном случае тоже не нужен, потому что функции применяются ко всем элементам в селекторе

Comment: @Grundy, согласен. Я туда сначала портянку с parent запихнул, а так да - тут всё вполне можно применить к набору.

Answer (score 2):

`each` - в данном случае не нужен, метод `on` может применяться к коллекции элементов.

Далее идея - выбираем активные элементы, кроме текущего, сбрасываем все, потом выбираем элемент по которому кликнули и выставляем нужные стили.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".catalogEntryItem").on("click",".catalogEntryItemTitle", function() {
        $('.active').not(this)
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .find('i').removeClass("arrowDown")
                    .end()
                    .next().slideToggle();;
        $(this).toggleClass('active')
               .find('i').toggleClass("arrowDown")
               .end()
               .next().slideToggle();;

        return false;
    })
});
```

Можно даже вынести применение стилей в функцию

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleStyle(elem){
        elem.toggleClass('active')
            .find('i').toggleClass("arrowDown")
            .end()
            .next().slideToggle();
    }

    $(".catalogEntryItem").on("click",".catalogEntryItemTitle", function() {
        toggleStyle($('.active').not(this));
        toggleStyle($(this));

        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: А этот код можно в jquery Cookie как нибудь засунуть?

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, что вы имеет ввиду? :) Правьте сразу исходный пост

Comment: `toggleStyle($('.active').not(this));
toggleStyle($(this));` - ты что-то перемудрил...

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему? :-) сначала ищем всех активных кроме текущего - применяем к ним `toggle` потом для текущего делаем то же самое - все правильно вроде

Comment: Если он уже `active`, то это делает одно и то же. Если это не так, то `not(this)` лишний. И вообще, похоже, надо `toggleStyle($('.active').add(this))`, после чего функция снова выпиливается.

Comment: А ещё можно `$(document).ready(function() {` заменить на `$(function() {`.

Comment: ага, с `add` лучше - просто не помнил есть такая функция или нет :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31880/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).