# Как поворачивать значок в зависимости от состояния списка?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы стрелка менялась относительно закрытого или открытого списка, как на скрине.Как это сделать?
Реализую выпадение так:

```js
$(".obj").click(function(){   
  $(this).next(".box1").toggle();
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <h4>Выбор по параметрам:</h4>
  <a class="obj">Обьем упаковки</a>
  <div class="box1">
    инфа
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавить списку класс (напр. `opened`) при открытии и менять картинку. по закрытию убирать класс - картинка вернётся

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468043/178988 + transition на transform.

Answer (score 3):

Все просто. Даже без js

```css
input {
  display:none;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s;
  
  }
input:checked + label > span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chbx">
<label for="chbx">Нажми меня! <span>&#9660;</span></label>
```